# Flask - Database -- RuntimeError: Working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I keep getting the below error regarding the **RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. when i use db.create_all() on terminal**
Please could someone point out where i'm going wrong.

```
from flask import Flask , render_template,url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
app= Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime,default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Error : This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `flask shell` in your terminal instead of `python` to get to a Python console.  This provides the Flask application context you need.

Answer (score 0):

or you can do so

```
@app.route('/create')
def create():
    db.create_all()
    return 'All tables created'
```

it should be in your main.py
then you navigate to your browser **localhost:port_number/create**