# Flask -- SQL -- RuntimeError: Working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    # completed = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Nothing of this helped me
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/
[RuntimeError: working outside of application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444036/runtimeerror-working-outside-of-application-context)
https://sentry.io/answers/working-outside-of-application-context/
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1308125/flask-raise-runtimeerrorworking-outside-of-application-context
[Flask - Database -- RuntimeError: Working outside of application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73973194/flask-database-runtimeerror-working-outside-of-application-context)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context." when creating blueprints with Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65744087/how-to-fix-runtimeerror-working-outside-of-application-context-when-creating)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: Note that the example code fails with a different error - `TemplateNotFound` if run and the `'/'` url is accessed.  Please ensure that your code is a [mre].